# jQuery Ajax Form Data settings convert to pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Found the answer thanks from Patrick Evans:**

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("gcd", "gcd");
    data.append("name", "name");
    
    ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(resopnse)
        {
            console.log(resopnse);
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
function ajax(options) {
    http_request.open(options.type || 'GET', options.url, true);
    http_request.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    http_request.send(options.data || null);
    http_request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
            if (http_request.status == 200) {
                var type = options.dataType || '';
                switch (type.toLowerCase()) {
                default: 
                    options.success(http_request.responseText);
                    break;
                case 'json': 
                    options.success(JSON.parse(http_request.responseText));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here is my Ajax test javascript using jQuery and Pure Javascript Ajax:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var url = "GRNM";
    var data = {
        gcd: "gcd",
        name: "name"
    };
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(resopnse)
        {
            console.log(resopnse);
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
    
    ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(resopnse)
        {
            console.log(resopnse);
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

**Pure Javascript Ajax:**

```
var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
function ajax(options) {
    http_request.open(options.type || 'GET', options.url, true);
    http_request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    http_request.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    http_request.send(JSON.stringify(options.data) || null);
    http_request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
            if (http_request.status == 200) {
                var type = options.dataType || '';
                switch (type.toLowerCase()) {
                default: 
                    options.success(http_request.responseText);
                    break;
                case 'json': 
                    options.success(JSON.parse(http_request.responseText));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the result:

**jQuery:** I could get the value data successfully

```
General:
    Request URL: http://gaspc-011:8888/GRNM
    Request Method: POST
    Status Code: 200 
    Remote Address: 192.168.1.120:8888
    Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Response Headers:
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 43
    Content-Type: application/json
    Date: Fri, 27 Aug 2021 06:20:37 GMT
    Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Request Headers:
    Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 17
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
    Host: gaspc-011:8888
    Origin: http://gaspc-011:8888
    Referer: http://gaspc-011:8888/index01
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Form Data:
    gcd: gcd
    name: name
```

**Pure Javascript:** I couldn't get the data

```
General:
    Request URL: http://gaspc-011:8888/GRNM
    Request Method: POST
    Status Code: 400 
    Remote Address: 192.168.1.120:8888
    Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Response Headers:
    Connection: close
    Content-Language: en-US
    Content-Type: text/html;charset=Shift_JIS
    Date: Fri, 27 Aug 2021 06:20:37 GMT
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Request Headers:
    Accept: */*
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 27
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
    Host: gaspc-011:8888
    Origin: http://gaspc-011:8888
    Referer: http://gaspc-011:8888/index01
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Form Data:
    {"gcd":"gcd","name":"name"}:
```

My Spring Boot Controller couldn't find the `gcd` and `name` parameter  that came from pure javascript because the Form Data format is different. I've also tried to use `FormData()` but couldn't make it work.

My Form Data becomes like this:

```
Form Data:
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryLgD8tjkxnVk4hfiE
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name: "gcd"

    gcd
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryLgD8tjkxnVk4hfiE
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

    name
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryLgD8tjkxnVk4hfiE--
```

I've also tried changing `http_request.send(JSON.stringify(options.data) || null);` to `http_request.send(options.data || null);` but didn't worked.

How can I achieve the same result as jQuery? How can I pass my `var data` object to controller using Ajax POST same as jQuery?

Comment: It is unclear what you are aslking. What is the code you used and what is the code you use now  - please split the answer and be clear what you need from us

Comment: @Teemu the data the controller couldn't use is the plain JS.

Comment: Just replace the curly braces with empty strings.

Comment: You are using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type for your `XMLHttpRequest`, but you supplied it a JSON text not the expected `key=value` param string. If you use the `FormData` object then the content-type needs to be `multipart/form-data`, which is automatically set when using `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`, for jQuery you have to set `processData` and `contentType` to `false`.

Comment: @mplungjan , my question is at the last part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply the correct content-type with the correct content.

If you want to send JSON text you have to use `application/json` content-type

```
http_request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
http_request.send(JSON.stringify(options.data));
```

If you want to use the `FormData` object you need the `multipart/form-data` content-type

```
let fd = new FormData();
for(let key in options.data){
  fd.append(key,options.data[key]);
}
//don't need to explicitly set content-type when sending FormData
//it will automatically do that
//http_request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
http_request.send(fd);
```

If you just want to use your object you will need to convert it to one of the previously mentioned methods or create a param string from it and use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type

```
//builds a param=value&param2=value2 type of string from your options.data object
let paramStrings = [];
for(let key in options.data){
  paramStrings.push(`${key}=${options.data[key]}`);
}
let data = paramStrings.join('&');

http_request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
http_request.send(data);
```

Comment: using `application/json`, the Spring Boot Controller couldn't read the parameter.
My Controller settings:
`@PostMapping(value="GRNM")
    @ResponseBody
    public String GRNM(@RequestParam(name = "gcd") String gcd, @RequestParam String name)`

but the `FormData()` worked so thank you.